# OnKey event to go to the last active sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a OnKey event.
When I copy a range from the CC sheet using CTRL+C, I want to return to the last active sheet, which is where I will manually paste the content.
I would like this code to work only in CC, to not get in the way of the rest of the worksheet.

I'm using this

```vb
Sub CTRLC()
    Application.OnKey "^{C}", "Aplication"
    Application.Sheets(LastSheet).Select
End Sub
```

Going to do a massive update.

First, I have this macro "CC", it pastes contents in the "FORMULAS" tab that I copied with CTRL C on a web page. When it pastes the Excel it jumps to the "FORMULAS" tab. To avoid this I hide this tab.

[image: Macro]

Worksheet "FORMULAS" bellow for reference

[image: FORMULAS]

When I run the "CC" macro, it pastes on "FORMULAS" and jumps to "CC" tab.

"CC" tab, ignore the buttons on the right.
[image: CC TAB]

In this worksheet I will copy this content from the first row of the table manually (it is pulled from the "FORMULAS" from some formulas I created), so that I copy I would like VBA to jump to the tab where I pressed the macro "CC".
Note that it is currently named "MODEL (2)", but this name is temporary and will not always be the same, so I would like to use a code that returns to a tab I recently visited.
However, when I run the "CC" macro, it pastes the contents into the "FORMULA" tab and jumps to it (I don't know how to avoid this), so I think that if you use a code in which when I copy the contents in the "CC" tab it jumps to the last active worksheet, it would jump to the "FORMULA" so it wouldn't do what I want.

VBA code Macro "CC"

```vb
Sub COLAR()
    Worksheets("FORMULAS").Range("A3:M90").ClearContents

    Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
    DataObj.GetFromClipboard
    
    SText = DataObj.GetText(1)
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORMULAS").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = SText
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("CC").Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: "last active sheet" or last sheet in the workbook?

Comment: The last sheet I've been in my workbook

Comment: OK. I will post a solution to bring you in the last activated sheet. But overwriting `Ctrl + C` is not the best option. I will try using a combination not so necessary/used as this one...

Comment: Please, try solution I suggested and send some feedback.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry I didn't explain my question properly

Comment: I am afraid you do not understand how `OnKey` works... It cancels the default behavior of the shortcut and allocate a new macro to it. So, you cannot press `Ctrl + C`  to simultaneously copy a range and run the macro, too. But, **if you  want copying something by pressing `Ctrl + C`, this means that a selection exists and the new code can start from this point**. I would try preparing it, but let me try a guess and you will confirm it, or better describe of what you want accomplishing (in a following comment).

Comment: So, you make a selection and using the shortcut, you need copying the selection content to `Sheets("FORMULAS").Range("A3")`.  Then, going back to the sheet where selection has been done (in fact, no need to activate the sheet where copying). Is this understanding correct? If yes, does **selection in discussion consist in only one cell**? Then, you need to all the time copy in these "A3" cell, or in the last empty cell of column A:A?

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now, you clarified my doubt now, I really thought that the CTRL C command could be used to copy the selected range and at the same time run the macro I was trying to create, so it would make it easier to always go back to the tab ( " MODELO (2)" example ), sorry for taking your time

Comment: But, is my above expressed scenario a correct one? I can adapt the answer code to do what you need, supposing that my understanding is correct. In your code are some strange things. No need of `DataObject`, no even need of clipboard. Selections, activations only consumes Excel resources making the code slower, without bringing any benefit...

Comment: Almost, I make a selection on a web page with CRTL C, then I use the macro button "CC" (tab "MODEL (2)" )

Comment: it will put the contents of the clipboard in "FORMULA" in a preformatted worksheet as if I was pasting the webpage in excel, this small table from the "CC" worksheet pulls the data from the "FORMULAS" and formats it to be 100% compatible with the "MODEL (2)", so in the "CC" I copy the data from this small table and paste it in the "MODEL (2)" (this worksheet is used for launching invoices for purchases of products and services) in this step that I would like CTRL C to do the work of running the macro (which you explained to me was not possible copy and run the macro)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot get you. I mean, in order to receive a piece of code doing what you need, what you ar telling is only a story. If you really need help, you must learn speaking in terms of ranges: After putting 'something' in clipboard, it must be copied in sheet "FORMULA" range "A3". The range compatibility with "MODEL (2)" is not relevant, it does not matter. From sheet "CC" the range "B3:Ix" is copied in sheet "MODEL (2)" range "Ax", then the sheet "CC" should be activated at range "A1"...

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way. It will be triggered by `Ctrl + Shift + I` keys combination:

1. Copy in `ThisWorkbook` code module the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Public lastActSheet As String

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()   'to make it working only for this workbook
   Application.OnKey "^+I", "GoToLastActiveSheet"
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()'to deactivate the new OnKey called Sub, when activate another one
   Application.OnKey "^+I"
End Sub
```

2. Copy the next code in a standard module:

a. Firstly a `Private` variable, on top of the module (in the declarations area):

```
Public wsLast As Worksheet
```

b. Secondly, copy the next `Sub` in this module (wherever you want):

```
Sub GoToLastActiveSheet()
    Dim shName As String:  shName = ThisWorkbook.lastActSheet
  
    If shName <> "" Then wsLast.Activate
End Sub
```

In order to firstly activate `OnKey` for this specific way of working, you should activate another workbook and come back (to trigger `Workbook_Activate` event). Next time when the workbook will be open, this event will be triggered, anyhow and no need to firstly activate another one...

If something not clear enough, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: When i open another workbook i get erron on "Aplication" =
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate() 'to deactivate the new OnKey called Sub, when activate another one
   Application.OnKey "^+I"

Comment: @Where did you see `"Aplication" = Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()`? Did you use the code as it is and only wrongly referred to the event?

Comment: Sorry i mean, i get an error on this
"Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate() 'to deactivate the new OnKey called Sub, when activate another one 
Application.OnKey "^+I"

On "Application.OnKey" , the first code you've provided

Comment: @Cooper What kind of error? Say only "I get an error" is useless... Did you try the code **exactly as it is**? Even with something which looks as a minor modification...

Comment: "Runtime error '1004'

Method 'OnKey' of object '_Appliccation' failed" , I copied all the codes as per your answer, the only line I changed was the module, from "Dim shName As String: shName = ThisWorkbook.lastActSheet" to "Dim shName As String:  shName = EstaPastaDeTrabalho.lastActSheet" because of the language difference ( EN to PT-BR )

Comment: @Cooper What is `EstaPastaDeTrabalho`? Where did you paste the code I suggested to be pasted in `ThisWorkbook` code module?

Comment: EstaPastaDeTrabalho equals ThisWorkbook , like i said, because of the language difference, i pasted in ThisWorkbook,, just changed the last code